# How does Ohio handle intestate inheritance of jointly owned property

Tags: united-states, real-estate, wills, probate, ohio

My best attempt to summarize the situation; Ohio property purchased as JTWROS by A, B, and C. A and B are married. C is adult child of A and B. Unfortunately, A suddenly passes, not leaving a will. Considering Ohio dower rights, what respective percentages of ownership do B and C now hold in the property?

Comment: There was no hint of a request for legal advice in the body of the question, only in the title. As edited, this is a classic question about what the law is, and there is no reason to close it.

Comment: I agree with @DavidSiegel

Answer (score 3):

Each party had a 33.3% interest in the real estate. When A dies, B gets A's share so has a 66.6% interest. Per Ohio intestate succession law and given that C is the child of A and B, B gets 100% of everything that is A's, see [ORC 2105.06(B)](https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/section-2105.06).

Comment: So C's 1/3 ownership as a member of the three member joint tenancy just goes "Poof"?

Comment: @DJohnM No, C still owns 1/3. B gets all of **A's** share, not all of the property. So B now owns what were A & B's share, that is a 2/3rds interest in the property.